# What activities needs to be done after AD password changed for SharePoint System account?

Tags: active-directory, password, system-account

Our company system team is going to change the Active Directory password for the SharePoint system account.

I need to know all activities I need to do post password change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171993/changing-password-through-ca-for-any-managed-account

Comment: Which account you mean by System account? farm admin account? do you have search and User profile sync configured in the farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you change the password and update the SharePoint with new password, after that make sure all app pools and timer service gets the new password. Update a sync with new password, then you are all set.
>
> I don't see any impact if process properly followed. Worst case scenario would be SharePoint goes down if you locked out the account.

Source: [Impact of changing System Account Password](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171820/impact-of-changing-system-account-password?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you rafael, for the answer. Could you please help me on;
1. How to update SharePoint password
2. Update a sync with new password
3. Check all app pools and timer services get new password

Comment: This should cover it all: http://www.mstechbits.com/sharepoint-2013/how-to-change-service-account-password-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: did you manage to figure it out @shoab ?

Comment: Tnks rafael, Below is my scenario and actions i will do as per that article;
Our's is 3 tier architecture SP farm. The IT team is gonna change the System Account password. The System Account (sp_admin) is been used for all SharePoint purposes like;
1)Application Pool identity (App Server & Web Server)
2)Run services (Web Server) SharePoint 2010 Administration, User Code Host, Search, Timer and Web Analytics.
3)These same services on (App Server) along with Forefront Identity Manager &  Sync services
4)Managed account on App & Web server
I will update pwd all these places. Crt me if wrong

Comment: Dear Rafael, Could you please verify my steps and comment on it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @shoab. Yes, you are right.

Comment: No problem! Let us know how it worked out.